# Querying XML data in sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, xml

i got a snippet which show how to query xml data in sql server but few area still not clear to me.

```
DECLARE @xml XML 
SET @xml = '<root>
  <row>one</row>
  <row>two</row>
  <row>three</row>
</root>'

CREATE TABLE #Fields(Field varchar(MAX))

INSERT INTO #Fields
SELECT 
    x.y.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(5)') 
FROM @xml.nodes('root/row') x(y)

SELECT * FROM #Fields
DROP TABLE #Fields
```

what is `x.y` i just do not understand and also what kind of syntax is it `'text()[1]', 'varchar(5)'`

if `text()` is in-built function then does it work for any data type ?

please help me to visualize what `x.y` ?? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.nodes()` call converts your XML into a **list of XML fragments** - and a "list" in SQL Server always is a **table** - so this is really a **table alias** (`x`) and a **column alias** (`y`) for an internally constructed tables of XML fragments (one "row" per match for `.nodes()`)

If you would be using `.nodes('/root`)` then you'd get an "pseudo table" with these rows:

Table `x`

```
y
----------------
<row>one</row>
<row>two</row>
<row>three</row>
```

Since you're using `.nodes('/root/row')` instead, you're really getting just the values of those `<row>` elements:

Table `x`

```
y
----------------
one
two
three
```

The `.value()` now takes one of those XML fragments and returns something from it. It could be the name of a sub-element - but `text()` (yes, a built-in XQuery function) just converts the whole XML fragment into a textual representation. The second parameter of the `.value()` call just defines what that value should be treated as - what datatype.